# Print received messages while prompting user for input in a chat program

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am creating a chat application on Python without the use of non standard libraries and I've encountered a problem while prompting a user for a message and a message comes through.

```
def printit():
    threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
    print("This is a test message!")

def prompt():
    while True:
        msg = input("Your Message: ")

def main():
    thread_prompt = threading.Thread(target = prompt)
    thread_prompt.start()
    printit()
```

While I would like any received messages to display on a different line from the prompt, what happens at the moment is this (e.g. User is trying to type and send "hello world"):

```
Your Message: hello worThis is a test message!
```

While I want it to be like the following:

```
This is a test message!
Your Message: hello wor
```

Is this possible to achieve without the use of external libraries? Also, I've yet to implement sockets/server that sends messages back so for now I am using `threading.Timer` to imitate a message that comes through every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can easily do what you want in this particular order (the test message followed by the prompt), but the reverse order (the prompt followed by the test message) is easily achievable. Instead of printing the test message, *queue* it and later print all queued messages when the user presses Enter.

```
queue = []
lock = threading.Lock()

def printit():
    threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
    lock.acquire()
    queue.append("This is a test message!")
    lock.release()

def prompt():
    global queue
    while True:
        msg = input("Your Message: ")      
        lock.acquire()
        while queue:
            print(queue.pop())
        lock.release()

def main():
    thread_prompt = threading.Thread(target = prompt)
    thread_prompt.start()
    printit()
```